# How do I add to a x position with draw.RoundedBox using a variable?

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I am currently trying to create an XP system that allows you to gain experience and level up by killing NPCs. I was able to setup the actual XP bar and set the width to my variable "xp". When I have "xp" set to something like 100 it shows a bar with a width of 100. However, when I added a function hook that activated whenever a player killed an NPC to add +1 to the variable "xp", it did not affect the width of the bar. Is there another way I should be going about this so that the XP Bar updates with the variable "xp".

```
--init.lua file--

AddCSLuaFile("cl_init.lua")

levels = 0
xp = 0

hook.Add("OnNPCKilled", "npcreward", function()

    xp = xp + 1
    print(xp)

end)

--cl_init.lua file--

hook.Add("HUDPaint", "DrawMyHud", function()
    --XP Bar Background
    draw.RoundedBox(0,1598,8,300+4 , 30 + 4,Color(12, 120, 150))
    --XP Bar Progress Bar
    draw.RoundedBox(0,1600,10,xp,30,Color(28, 174, 214))
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that you have wrong here, and a couple of solutions to your problem.

As a base layer:
You have posted 2 file examples.
init.lua (Which is the server)
cl_init.lua (which only the client can see)

The first problem here is that you are incrementing a global variable (XP) on the server side, which is not sent to the client.
This variable has to be assigned to the player, and networked (sent from the server over to the client), orelse the client will never be able to see what's happening.

What you can do is assign the variable like this:
https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/GM:OnNPCKilled

-- init.lua --

```
util.AddNetworkString("npcreward:givexp")
hook.Add("OnNPCKilled", "NPCReward", function(npc,killer,weapon) -- NPC is the npc you are wanting to kill, killer is you, weapon is what was used to kill the NPC

net.Start("npcreward:givexp")
net.WriteInt(1,8)
net.Send(killer)
 -- What this will do is send the amount of xp you want to give to the client (in this case, you), to the client, so they can print it somewhere, in this case, a hud / progress bar.

end)
```

-- cl_init.lua --
Here you would draw the boxes / roundedboxes as you did, but one thing you missed was defining what the maximum amount of xp is. Not doing this will not allow you to make a dynamic XP bar, which changes based on the amount of XP you have.

Some other things you should look into is scaling by screen width/ screen height (ScrW(), ScrH()), because what you are making now, will maybe look okay on your screen, but maybe not mine, if I run a different resolution. This is important to think about, if you want this to work for other people.

For the purpose of this post, I will put in an example of how this progress bar could work, along with the code from init.lua.

```
--[[
    Everything that happens here, in the client realm, is only shared with the client.
    Unless you network something to the server, it will be unknown to the server, until you have told it whatever you want to send.
]]

local xp = 0
local maxExperience = 100
--[[
    If you look at the example in init.lua, you can see that this is the opposite of sending. We are now receiving the data that the server has sent to us.
]]
net.Receive("npcreward:givexp", function()
    local xpReward = net.ReadInt(8)

    --[[
        Printing xpReward should now give us (1), for the first NPC we kill.
        It will keep printing 1, because that's the amount of XP we receive.
    
        Using the variable "xp", that we have defined above, allows us to keep track of it, for this session, or until the code is refrehsed.
    
    The below code does this:
    I want xp to be the value of xp + the xp reward that I got from the server
    You can do the opposite if you want to remove XP, just make the "+" a "-"
    ]]
    xp = xp + xpReward

    --[[
        What we have now achieved is that the client now knows how much XP we have.
        We can now move on to painting this on our screen
    ]]
end)

hook.Add("HUDPaint", "npcreward:prog", function()

    -- Draw a background box

    draw.RoundedBox(8, ScrW()*.5, ScrH()*.7, ScrW()*.3, ScrH()*.1, Color(33,33,33,255))

   
    --[[
        Draw the same box, but this one will show how much progress you have made, so it will receive a lighter shade of gray.
         To explain in short what we are doing here.
        We are placing the box on the middle of our screen
        The box will be placed at 70% of screen height (near bottom)
        It will be 30% of the screen width wide
        And 10% of the screen height tall

        In basic terms what we are going to do, we are going to make the width change based on how much XP you have, and how much XP you need to achieve for the bar to be full
        
        So basic math:
        (maxExperience is 100xp)
            xp / maxExperience = 0 (Currently)

            if we receive 1 xp
            xp / maxExperience = 0.01
            What this means is that if we have 1 xp, 1% of the bar will draw.
            If you get 50 xp 50% of the bar will draw.
        ]]
    draw.RoundedBox(8, ScrW()*.5, ScrH()*.7, ScrW()*.3 * math.Clamp((xp / maxExperience),0,1), ScrH()*.1, Color(66,66,66,255))

end)
```

From this point on, I recommend learning about the use of net library, understanding the difference between server and client, and do not be hesitant to ask any questions.

You can also check out SetNWInt, GetNWInt, but I made this example to show you the way of networking.
https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/Entity:SetNWInt
https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/Entity:GetNWInt

I have to also let you know that all the code given here is untested, and can contain errors, but i hope it gives you a basic understanding of why your code didn't work, and what you have to do to make it work.

Good luck on future coding endeavours!

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still new to lua so my apologies for all the mistakes lol. Ill try the network libraries

Comment: Absolutely no worries! We've all been there.